# Magento 2.3 : How to add Custom button on a custom grid in customer view Adminhtml

Tags: magento2, grid

You have already answer this question , I have to do this in magento2. How can i do?Where i have to add this code[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add code inside `<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">` tag

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Button name</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/redirect-url</item>
        </item>
    </item>
```

in the xml responsible for rendering the grid.

If you grid is rendering from block file add below code in Grid.php

```
public function getMainButtonsHtml()
{
    $html = parent::getMainButtonsHtml();//get the parent class buttons
    $addButton = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button')
        ->setData(array(
        'label'     => 'Button Name',
        'onclick'   => "setLocation('redirect-url')",
        'class'   => 'task'
    ))->toHtml();
    return $addButton.$html;
}
```

Comment: here i had prepare a grid via block file, so how can i use this xml.

Comment: Updated the answer with PHP code as well @Raji

Comment: Thank you, i got answer

Comment: Is the answer different from what I added...if yes please share

Comment: Here i want to create a modal when this button was clicked....So i have to pass this url in this function  'onclick'   => "setLocation('redirect-url')",... Is there an idea from your side..